# Proportional resize image

Tags: image, resolution

Blender added an option to resize images in the Image Editor - Image - Resize
I wanted to know if anyone knows a way to make it proportional resizing given a maximum x or y, similar to what Photoshop and other programs do.
I know you can do x/2 and y/2 to resize with uneven portions, but lets say I want x to 1024 and the image to keep its ratio. Do I need a script for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag your cursor to both slider to get the correct aspect ratio:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks!
That already helps but how did you manage to control both sliders?

Comment: @Miguel Uh drag your cursor from the top slider to the bottom slider and slide them

Comment: Perfect, that is a nice feature.